# Cursor to select max date without MAX function or subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am required to use an explicit cursor with a parameter that accepts car registration to find the most recent reservation made on the car. I cannot use the 
MAX function. I have to compare all the relevant dates to find the most recent one.

This is what I have so far"

```
Declare
  v_rec_date DATE; 
    Cursor date_cur (v_reg VARCHAR2) IS 
    SELECT * FROM i_booking
    WHERE registration = v_reg;
    v_date date_cur%ROWTYPE;
  Begin
   FOR v_date IN date_cur LOOP 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Recent Rental Date:'|| ' '||v_rec_date); 
   END LOOP;
  End;
```

However this is giving me the error:

```
FOR v_date IN date_cur LOOP
              *
ERROR at line 8: 
ORA-06550: line 8, column 15: 
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DATE_CUR' 
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1: 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You've created a parameterized cursor but you're not passing in any parameters.

When this line executes:
    FOR v_date IN date_cur LOOP

You need to be passing a value for v_reg  since that's how you designed the cursor.

Check out the Oracle docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#BABGJBEA) for examples.

Specifically take a look at the section in the link titled "Example 6-20 Passing Parameters to Explicit Cursor FOR LOOP Statement" where they're doing pretty much exactly what you're attempting here.

When you declare a cursor like you have here: **Cursor date_cur (v_reg VARCHAR2)** you're saying that when you open this cursor you will be passing the parameter referenced as v_reg to the cursor and that v_reg will be a VARCHAR2 type.

When you then try to use your cursor here: **FOR v_date IN date_cur LOOP**  the error you're receiving basically says, "You promised to include a parameter when you open the cursor date_cur but you didn't give me one."

Here's what you had but with a parameter now being passed to the cursor.

```
   Declare
  v_rec_date DATE; 
    Cursor date_cur (v_reg VARCHAR2) IS 
    SELECT * FROM i_booking
    WHERE registration = v_reg;
    v_date date_cur%ROWTYPE;
  Begin
   FOR v_date IN date_cur("SOME VALUE HERE") LOOP 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Recent Rental Date:'|| ' '||v_rec_date); 
   END LOOP;
  End;
```

Comment: Sadly I am not sure what you mean... This goes above my head.

Comment: @Splunk - I updated the answer with some additional detail. If you take a look at the example and don't understand what it's doing I would suggest reading Oracle's introduction to cursors. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html

Comment: Thanks Carth, I appreciate your replies.  I have looked at the documents and tried Declare
cursor c1 (v_reg VARCHAR2) IS
Select * from i_booking
WHERE registration = v_reg;
Begin
FOR registration IN c1 
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(registration);
END LOOP;
END; However I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Splunk I added an updated example of your code to my answer. Note the "SOME VALUE HERE" parameter.

Comment: I see.  So this means I need to actually select an individual registration?  Is there a way where it just show all results for all registrations?

Comment: Remove the parameter argument from your cursor declaration and remove the where clause from the cursor and you would get everything in i_booking.

Comment: But without the parameter, how will the query know which is the most recent date reserved for each individual registration?

Comment: @Splunk Sorry Splunk but I don't see how it would know that now. I think your best bet is to write this out as psuedocode to make sure you know how you want to address the problem then begin the building the logic into these statements to do that.